# Creating an alarm for aws cloud watch when instance gets stopped/rebooted

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-cloudwatch, infrastructure, cloudwatch-alarms

I have been trying to create cloudwatch alarm when instance gets stopped but couldn't find direct way. From event subscriptions i can send notification when instance gets stopped. Is there any way cloud watch alarm can be triggered for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EventBridge can be configured to trigger an event when a state change occurs on an EC2 instance. Use:

- Event source: `EC2`
- Event type: `EC2 Instance State-change Notification`

You can setup a target for the event to be a Lambda

The Lambda can [API_PutMetricData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutMetricData.html) for a metric you create. You can setup a CloudWatch Alarm on this metric

[This tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-log-ec2-instance-state.html) shows you how to setup the EventBridge rule and the Lambda.